# print and save matrix in fortran

Tags: fortran

Hello everyone I am new to Fortran and I am facing a problem. Let s assume I have a matrix a(5,50)

```
a1      a2       a3       a4      a5         a6        a7      etc 
b1      b2       b3       b4      b5         b6        b7      etc
c1      c2       c3       c4      c5         c6        c7      etc
d1      d2       d3       d4      d5         d6        d7      etc
e1      e2       e3       e4      e5         e6        e7      etc
```

is there a way to save it into a file and print the matrix like the following

```
a1     b1    c1    d1     e1
a2     b2    c2    d2     e2
a3     b3    c3    d3     e3
            etc
```

without saving it to another matrix? Because ok i can always do a loop and save it to a new matrix and then save that to a file and print it. I have also created a subroutine to print my matrix in a correct order and be presentable

Answer (score 2):

Sure.

You could loop over the first index, then write the whole column:

```
do ii = 1, 50
    write(unit, '(5(I7))') a(ii, :)
end do
```

Or you could use `transpose`:

```
write(unit, '(5(I7))') transpose(a)
```

(I'm assuming that `a` is an integer array and that all values can be written with 6 or fewer digits (including sign). Change the format if that's not the case.)

This computer doesn't have a fortran compiler, so I haven't tested it, but it should work.

Cheers

Comment: Hey! I thought about transpose but for some reason I thought it would not print it the way I wanted to. I guess my brain just shut down! Thank you very much it worked perfectly with the subroutine I have for the write statement!

Comment: If it worked so well maybe you could mark the answer as right, and give an upvote as some credit for the help you have received?